# Adding event to calendar via Google Apps script - error when calculating end time more than one hour after start

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a simple app in which users complete some basic details of a meeting in a google sheet and then export these to their google calendar. Script as follows:

```
function exportEvents() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var headerRows = 1;  
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var data = range.getValues();
  // var calId = sheet.getRange("H2:H2").getValue();
  var calId = "xxxxxxxxxxxx";
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calId);

  for (i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
    if (i < headerRows) continue; 
    var row = data[i];
    var date = new Date(row[1]); 
    var title = row[2];          
    var initial = row[0];
    var concatTitle = initial + " - " + title;
    var tstart = new Date(row[3]);
    tstart.setDate(date.getDate());
    tstart.setMonth(date.getMonth());
    tstart.setYear(date.getYear());
    // var tstop = new Date(row[4]);
    var tstop = new Date(tstart + row[4]);
    tstop.setDate(date.getDate());
    tstop.setMonth(date.getMonth());
    tstop.setYear(date.getYear());
    var loc = row[5];
    var desc = row[6];
    var id = row[7];              
    try {
      var event = cal.getEventSeriesById(id);
    }
    catch (e) {
      // do nothing - we just want to avoid the exception when event doesn't exist
    }
    if (!event) {
      var newEvent = cal.createEvent(concatTitle, tstart, tstop, {description:desc,location:loc}).getId();
      row[7] = newEvent;  
    }
    else {
      event.setTitle(concatTitle);
      event.setDescription(desc);
      event.setLocation(loc);
      var recurrence = CalendarApp.newRecurrence().addDailyRule().times(1);
      event.setRecurrence(recurrence, tstart, tstop);
    }
    debugger;
  }
  range.setValues(data);
}
```

The whole thing works great, except for when the user puts more than 60 mins as the length of the meeting in column 4. Anything up to 59 mins works great and the event is logged with the correct start and end time. However, when I enter 60 or more mins, the error reads 'Event start time must be before event end time."

I'm sure I'm doing something very simple very wrong, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This should do the trick: `var tstop = new Date(tstart.getTime() + eventLengthInMinutes * 60000);`

Comment: Amazing! Thanks so much Chris G